# npm run dev command not giving the correct output

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning to use Laravel from a Youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImtZ5yENzgE&t=29s).

It says to use the command `npm run dev` to compile the files, but I am getting a different output and I am stuck. The output is supposed to be 'Finished. Please run mix again' after compiling and I would be able to run `npm run dev` one more time.  When I run the command, this is what I get:

```
    npm run dev

> dev
> vite


  vite v2.9.14 dev server running at:

  > Local: http://localhost:3000/
  > Network: use `--host` to expose

  ready in 347ms.


  Laravel v9.20.0 

  > APP_URL: http://project.test
```

When I get the output above, I am no longer able to give any commands and have to close the tab and open it again.
The localhost url gives me a not found page.

I was looking online to see if I can find any solutions for this problem but all of them are not solved. Does anyone know what to do? Also, I am using a MacBook Air with the M1 chip.

Comment: If the version of Laravel on the YouTube video is not the same as the version of Laravel you're using, you can't expect things to match 1:1. The video is for version 5.8, but you're using 9.20. Either install the correct version for the tutorial you're using, or review the documentation for Laravel 9: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation

Comment: @TimLewis I understand, I am just asking what is the equivalent for Laravel 9 for this command.

Comment: There is no equivalent... It's the same command; they just do different things on version 5.8 vs 9.20. You're not getting any kind of error or anything. Once again, please read the documentation for the current version of Laravel to see how to get it up and running, find a more up-to-date tutorial, or use Laravel 5.8 instead of 9.20.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the current version of Vite in PHP 9.x.
What you can try, is paste this in the `package.json`(remove the current code):

```
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.2.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "vite": "^2.9.11",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
    },
    "name": "minicrm",
    "description": "<p align=\"center\"><a href=\"https://laravel.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/art/master/logo-lockup/5%20SVG/2%20CMYK/1%20Full%20Color/laravel-logolockup-cmyk-red.svg\" width=\"400\"></a></p>",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "vite.config.js",
    "directories": {
        "test": "tests"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "acorn": "^8.7.1",
        "acorn-import-assertions": "^1.8.0",
        "ajv": "^6.12.6",
        "ajv-keywords": "^3.5.2",
        "anymatch": "^3.1.2",
        "binary-extensions": "^2.2.0",
        "braces": "^3.0.2",
        "browserslist": "^4.21.1",
        "buffer-from": "^1.1.2",
        "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001363",
        "chokidar": "^3.5.3",
        "chrome-trace-event": "^1.0.3",
        "clone-deep": "^4.0.1",
        "colorette": "^2.0.19",
        "commander": "^2.20.3",
        "cross-spawn": "^7.0.3",
        "electron-to-chromium": "^1.4.182",
        "enhanced-resolve": "^5.10.0",
        "envinfo": "^7.8.1",
        "es-module-lexer": "^0.9.3",
        "esbuild": "^0.14.48",
        "esbuild-darwin-arm64": "^0.14.48",
        "escalade": "^3.1.1",
        "eslint-scope": "^5.1.1",
        "esrecurse": "^4.3.0",
        "estraverse": "^4.3.0",
        "events": "^3.3.0",
        "fast-deep-equal": "^3.1.3",
        "fast-json-stable-stringify": "^2.1.0",
        "fastest-levenshtein": "^1.0.12",
        "fill-range": "^7.0.1",
        "find-up": "^4.1.0",
        "follow-redirects": "^1.15.1",
        "fsevents": "^2.3.2",
        "function-bind": "^1.1.1",
        "glob-parent": "^5.1.2",
        "glob-to-regexp": "^0.4.1",
        "graceful-fs": "^4.2.10",
        "has": "^1.0.3",
        "has-flag": "^4.0.0",
        "immutable": "^4.1.0",
        "import-local": "^3.1.0",
        "interpret": "^2.2.0",
        "is-binary-path": "^2.1.0",
        "is-core-module": "^2.9.0",
        "is-extglob": "^2.1.1",
        "is-glob": "^4.0.3",
        "is-number": "^7.0.0",
        "is-plain-object": "^2.0.4",
        "isexe": "^2.0.0",
        "isobject": "^3.0.1",
        "jest-worker": "^27.5.1",
        "json-parse-even-better-errors": "^2.3.1",
        "json-schema-traverse": "^0.4.1",
        "kind-of": "^6.0.3",
        "klona": "^2.0.5",
        "loader-runner": "^4.3.0",
        "locate-path": "^5.0.0",
        "merge-stream": "^2.0.0",
        "mime-db": "^1.52.0",
        "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
        "nanoid": "^3.3.4",
        "neo-async": "^2.6.2",
        "node-releases": "^2.0.5",
        "normalize-path": "^3.0.0",
        "p-limit": "^2.3.0",
        "p-locate": "^4.1.0",
        "p-try": "^2.2.0",
        "path-exists": "^4.0.0",
        "path-key": "^3.1.1",
        "path-parse": "^1.0.7",
        "picocolors": "^1.0.0",
        "picomatch": "^2.3.1",
        "pkg-dir": "^4.2.0",
        "punycode": "^2.1.1",
        "randombytes": "^2.1.0",
        "readdirp": "^3.6.0",
        "rechoir": "^0.7.1",
        "resolve": "^1.22.1",
        "resolve-cwd": "^3.0.0",
        "resolve-from": "^5.0.0",
        "rollup": "^2.75.7",
        "safe-buffer": "^5.2.1",
        "schema-utils": "^3.1.1",
        "serialize-javascript": "^6.0.0",
        "shallow-clone": "^3.0.1",
        "shebang-command": "^2.0.0",
        "shebang-regex": "^3.0.0",
        "source-map": "^0.6.1",
        "source-map-js": "^1.0.2",
        "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
        "supports-color": "^8.1.1",
        "supports-preserve-symlinks-flag": "^1.0.0",
        "tapable": "^2.2.1",
        "terser": "^5.14.1",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.3",
        "to-regex-range": "^5.0.1",
        "update-browserslist-db": "^1.0.4",
        "uri-js": "^4.4.1",
        "watchpack": "^2.4.0",
        "webpack": "^5.73.0",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
        "webpack-sources": "^3.2.3",
        "which": "^2.0.2",
        "wildcard": "^2.0.0"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```